# Model data has special characters ( like ' and " )" )which needs to be shown HTML form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, special-characters, forms

Here's the requirement
I've got a string which has to be read from Database and shown it on the HTML UI form. User can perform operations like select a different string and save it to database.

Here the string could accept special characters like ' and ) as well.
For example , string could be some thing like **Hōnaunau-Napo'opo'o)**
Since this is coming from Model in the corresponding Javascript code 
I've coded to access the same

**var cityname = '@Model.CityName'**

Because of the *city name containing **'** and **)** it's invalidating the HTML*.

How do we fix this Issue ? Thanks much.

Comment: Is that C# or JavaScript samplecode?

Comment: How about replacing the special chars with corresponding HTML code (e.g. `)` converted to `&#41;`)? See the table here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

Comment: Moderators can help me here. I'm not sure whom to choose an answer @RomanoZumbé

Comment: That is totally up to you. Nobody judges. Just choose what you feel helped you best

Comment: Sure @RomanoZumbé thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.CityName))
```

Special characters will be converted to their corresponding HTML codes